# Hystrix command fails with "timed-out and no fallback available"

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, hystrix

I've noticed that some of the commands in my application fail with

```
Caused by: ! com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: GetAPICommand timed-out and no fallback available.
out: ! at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.getFallbackOrThrowException(HystrixCommand.java:1631)
out: ! at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.access$2000(HystrixCommand.java:97)
out: ! at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$TimeoutObservable$1$1.tick(HystrixCommand.java:1025)
out: ! at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$1.performBlockingGetWithTimeout(HystrixCommand.java:621)
out: ! at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$1.get(HystrixCommand.java:516)
out: ! at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.execute(HystrixCommand.java:425)
out: Caused by: ! java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
out: !... 11 common frames omitted
```

This is my Hystrix configuration override:

```
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=210000
hystrix.threadpool.default.coreSize=50
hystrix.threadpool.default.maxQueueSize=100
hystrix.threadpool.default.queueSizeRejectionThreshold=50
```

What kind of timeout is this? Is it a read/connection timeout to the external application? How do I go about debugging this?

Answer (score 40):

This is a Hystrix Command Timeout, this timeout is enabled by default per each command, you define the value using the property:

> **execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds:**
>   This property sets the time in milliseconds after which the caller will 
>   observe a timeout and walk away from the command execution. Hystrix marks > the HystrixCommand as a TIMEOUT, and performs fallback logic.

So you can increase your timeout value or disable the default time out (if apply in your case) for your command using the property:

`@HystrixProperty(name = "hystrix.command.default.execution.timeout.enabled", value = "false")`

You can find more information here: https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration#CommandExecution

Comment: What happens if you catch HystrixTimeoutException and return your own kind of exception? Will the circuit breaker still work? Or does the exception need to propagate somewhere?

Comment: @RobinJonsson The exception is called `HystrixRuntimeException` and it's the same exception for timeout as for if the command threw another exception.

Comment: Where is it to config @HystrixProperty? Are there zuul?

Answer (score 19):

It might be you are in debug or your connection too slow, default thread execution timeout is only 1 second, so you could get this message easily if you put a break-point in your command let's say

Although this is not your case but might help somebody else

Comment: This is what i experienced!

Answer (score 2):

After adding the following dependency

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.netflix.hystrix</groupId>
        <artifactId>hystrix-javanica</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.18</version>
    </dependency>
```

I would be able to resolve the timeout issue.

What you need to do is to set the `hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=210000`  property in the application.properties or bootstrap.properties

This works for me hopefully would work.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the stacktrace this is an exception thrown by Hystrix after the 210 seconds you defined above.

As `TimeoutException` is a checked exception that needs to be declared on each method that could throw this exception. You would see this declared in the `run()` method of your code.

You can debug this like any other program, but be aware that the `run()` method runs in a thread separate from the caller. After 210 seconds the caller will just continue despite your debugging session.

Comment: My run() method is just a GET HTTP call that looks like this. This is a jersey client.       ClientResponse response = client.resource(buildUri())
        .get(ClientResponse.class);

Comment: This is my code. Like I said it is a jersey client<code>@Override
  protected FetchProvisionedIdsResponse run() throws Exception {
    ClientResponse response = client.resource(buildUri())
        .get(ClientResponse.class);
    return response.getEntity(MyResponse.class);</code>
  }

Comment: You have declared `Exception` in the method, a good style is to narrow it down. From the API description I see that `get()` will throw a `UniformInterfaceException`, but no `TimeoutException`. Therefore it's Hystrix throwing this exception.

Answer (score -2):

You should increase ur rest client httpclient readTimeout property