# How to set custom Feign client connection timeout?

Tags: java, hystrix, feign

I have Spring Boot application with this Gradle dependencies:

```
compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka")
compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-feign")
compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-ribbon")
compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-hystrix")
compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config")
```

Also I have Feign client:

```java
@FeignClient(name = "client")
public interface FeignService {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/path", method = GET)
    String response();

}
```

My `application.properties`:

```
client.ribbon.listOfServers = http://localhost:8081
ribbon.eureka.enabled=false
```

When query time is more than 1 second I get exception:

```
com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: response timed-out and no fallback available.
```

**So my question is:** how can I set custom Feign client connection timeout? For example to 2 seconds.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I solved my problem using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33962251/2893903) on question: **[Hystrix command fails with “timed-out and no fallback available”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27375557/hystrix-command-fails-with-timed-out-and-no-fallback-available)**.

I added `hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=4000` to my `application.properties` to set custom timeout.

Comment: Glad to help you!

Comment: @Roman you can also do fine-grained timeout control for each method using operation name:
`hystrix.command."FeignService#sayHello(String)".execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds: 20000`

Comment: How do I change the timeout for maven projects??

Comment: Do you have any github link on how you added the timeout and solved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can be configured timeout using configuration properties on application.yaml file:

```
feign:
  client:
    config:
      default:
        connectTimeout: 5000
        readTimeout: 5000
```

Notice that this will change your default feign configuration, if you want to update the timeouts just for your client replace `default` with the name configured in `@FeignClient` in your case it will be `client`, another thing is that you must specify both `connectTimeout` and `readTimeout` for this to take effect.

For more detail see this: [documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html#spring-cloud-feign-overriding-defaults)