# Why does feign client timeout setting (as in documentation) not works?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-feign

I try to configure feign client connect timeout, as defined on [official documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/reference/html/), but it does not work.
The app is just simple demo app.

MyFeign.java

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;

@FeignClient(name = "myFeign", url = "localhost:9047/payroll", configuration = FeignConfig.class)
public interface MyFeign {

    @GetMapping(value = "/api/master/{employee_id}")
    ResponseEntity<String> disableMasterPayroll(@PathVariable(name = "employee_id") String employeeId);

}
```

1st attempt : using configuration class
FeignConfig.java

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import feign.Request;

@Configuration
public class FeignConfig {

    public Request.Options feignRequestOptionsCustom() {
        return new Request.Options(5000, 5000);
    }

}
```

2nd attempt, using application.yml as defined on spring doc (copy-paste it)

```
feign:
  hystrix:
    enabled: false
  client:
    config:
      default:
        connectTimeout: 5000
        readTimeout: 5000
        loggerLevel: basic
```

But none works.
Found several question on stackoverflow ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46526431/cant-configure-feign-client-timeouts), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41470321/how-to-set-custom-feign-client-connection-timeout)), but none resolve it.
I did not use hystrix. This is my gradle file

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}
```

I'm using boot 2.2 with spring cloud Hoxton.RELEASE.
Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried using those timeouts with ribbon? Usually works.

Comment: Nope, after all ribbon is no longer reccomended. So I use spring cloud LB